# Do Angular module imports work nested?

Tags: angular, module

Let's say app.module imports AntModule, and AntModule imports BeeModule, and BeeModule exports StingComponent.

Will app.module get the reference to StingComponent, or does it need to directly import BeeModule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do Angular module imports work nested?

No, they don't

> Will app.module get the reference to StingComponent, or does it need
>   to directly import BeeModule?

Yes, you need directly to import the `BeeModule` and also you need to export `StingComponent` from the `BeeModule` to make it available for use for the components of the `AppModule`.

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [StingComponent],
   exports: [StingComponent]
})
export class BeeModule { }
```

Comment: Another thing to note, is that the `AntModule` could re-export the `BeeModule`.

Comment: yes, that will work, but I think it will be a bit confusing